# How to use touch ID instead of user password?

Tags: mac, administrator, touch-id

My Macbook keyboard has a touch ID button in the top right corner. When performing tasks that require elevated privileges (such as installing new apps) I'm asked to input my user password. I'd like to use touch ID instead. My user is an administrator.

Is it possible?

Comment: Just to be clear it might be helpful if you added a screen shot of one of these password requests to your question, along with the steps required to get to that request. We are not looking over your shoulder so a little more info might be a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the touch ID should indeed work where the password is required. Unless it has been 48 hours, the laptop has been restarted or the fingerprint failed 5 times, the laptop should ask for the TouchID in such instances.

Of course, you must enroll the finger print into the TouchID settings first. Until enrolled, the TouchID is not activated. (note TouchID is NOT Apple Pay. It supports Apple Pay, but one can enroll a fingerprint and not enable Apple Pay.)